# Ruby: retrieve local_variables from a block or append code within a block

Tags: ruby, scope, metaprogramming, block, dsl

I want access to local variables declared by the user of my DSL in a block.

E.g.

```
class Scraper
  def scrape!(&block)

    a = block.binding
    instance_eval &block
    b = block.binding

    p "b] Notice that the variable named variable no longer exists here..."
    eval("p local_variables", a)

    p "or here ..."
    eval("p local_variables", b)

    p "Although, when we rerun the proc, all is still as it was..."
    pr = block.to_proc
    pr.call
    c = pr.binding
    p "Still nothing here though..."
    eval("p local_variables", c)
  end
end

s = Scraper.new
s.scrape! do
  variable = "some_value"
  p "A] Notice that the variable named variable clearly exists here..."
  p local_variables
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think you are passing something to local_variables method in your eval, to demonstrate that the variable is no longer there, this is not what is happening in your code.

Local variables are indeed local, so the scope changes, and when the scope changes, the local variables that are local to your scope change are different than the ones that you are looking at, in another scope.

To get at those local variables, you must be in that context.  Self must be that object and then you will have access to those local variables.

So it isn't hat the variable called 'variable' no longer exists in those areas, it is that that variable never existed in the scope you are in.

Local variables are not meant to be long lived, really.

Now how to get to them?  You can get to the contents by making it the last evaluation of a method.

Comment: That is what I was trying to illustrate with my example, how can I add a line to return binding from within proc?

Comment: I realize my answer is 9 years later, but to return binding from within a proc: `my_proc = proc { my_local = 123; binding }; proc_bindning = my_proc.call; puts "my_local = #{proc_bindning.local_variable_get(:my_local)}"` So like @vgoff said all those years ago – make it the last thing evaluated in the block. In this simplified example, we could of course just have let `my_local` be the block's "return value" and not bothered with the `binding`.